# CSS styling for paragraph not taking effect in head but takes effect when declared in the body

Tags: html, css

I'm fairly a newbie at HTML and CSS. I've been following procedures on w3schools and also experimenting with things on my own. One of the first problems I've faces so far is in this code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>vector5 - Home</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
      <!-- Link Styling-->a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #6a9496;
      }

      a:visited {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #6a9496;
      }

      a:hover {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #6a9496;
      }

      a:focus {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #6a9496;
      }

      a:active {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #6a9496;
      }

      <!-- Paragraph Styling-->p {
        margin-top: 0px;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
        margin-right: 250px;
        margin-left: 100px;
        border: 10px solid powderblue;
        color: #757575;
        text-align: justify;
        font-size: 100%;
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
      }
    </style>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
  </head>
  <body style="background-color: #99bfc1;">
    <h1 style="color: #6a9496; font-family: 'Roboto'; font-size: 200%;">Lorem Di Ipsum</h1>
    <p style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-right: 250px; margin-left: 100px; border: 10px solid powderblue; color: #757575; text-align: justify; font-size: 100%; font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;"
      title="Lorem Di Ipsum">
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry, used for <b><abbr title="Hypertext Markup Language">HTML</abbr></b>    and design in modern times. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when a unknown
      printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries,
      but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with
      the release of Letraset sheets containing cursive cursive Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
      software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. To learn more about the <i>'Lorem Di Ipsum test'</i>,
      you can visit <a href="https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/www/justify.html" style="text-decoration: none;" target="_blank">this website</a>.
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

The styling for the paragraph works when I attribute it as a style with the paragraph element. However, when I deleted the style attributes with the paragraph element in the body and left the paragraph css styling in the head, within the style elements, the text in the browser reverted back to the default text *(black Times New Roman font)*. I don't understand what is going on or why my code works for the body, can anyone shed some light on this?

I also have another question. What should I do if I want to use the same font in the paragraph, but of different thickness?

Comment: It works fine for me when I remove the style attribute from your paragraph element.  Perhaps you just have an error in your code structure - post the entire html.  As for the "thickness", you can set the font-weight to bold, 100, 200, etc.

Comment: this will fine whene remove style from body so whats wrong

Comment: Yup, there were a few errors in the original code structure along with discovering that HTML comments can't be used within the CSS style element in the header!

Comment: Remove `:100` in link `https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100` to use all font widths

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a HTML comment in CSS either remove the comment or change too.

```
/*'Paragraph Styling' */
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. I didn't know that HTML comments couldn't be used inside the style element.

Answer (score 1):

> What should I do if I want to use the same font in the paragraph, but
>   of different thickness?

Use another tag inside `<p>`. May be `<b>`, `<strong>`, etc

> the text in the browser reverted back to the default text (black Times
>   New Roman font).

Check another css-styles for these elements ([Chrome DevTools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) can help)

Comment: Yes, but I was wondering if I could use a variation of the font. For example. I'm using Roboto in that code. On the Google fonts page, there's several variations such as Roboto light and Roboti light italic, but nowhere does it mention how to use these variations. I tried --> font-family: 'Roboto light' <-- but it's not working.

Comment: If this is only weight of font, you can use style `font-weight`. If this is another  font, you must add another font

Answer (score 1):

Declare your fonts at first link element of you page.